# Issue with the performance of the query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

I have two tables tab1 and tab2 each are having two columns acc_num and prod_code. I need to update prod_code in tab2 from tab1. Below is the sample data in both the tables:

```
TAB1

acnum      Prod
-------------------
1            A
2            B
2            C
3            X
3            X

Tab2

acnum        Prod
-------------------
1            null
2            null
2            null
3            null
3            null
```

And for the 2nd table after update all the distinct codes should be concatenated. Below is the sample output.

```
Tab2

acnum       Prod
-------------------
1            A
2            B|C
2            B|C
3            X
3            X
```

I am able to achieve this through PL/SQL, but it's taking ages to complete. (Actual tables are having millions of records). Below is the code I am using.

```
DECLARE
  l_acnum dbms_sql.varchar2a;
  l_prod dbms_sql.varchar2a;
  l_prod2 VARCHAR2(10):= NULL;
  l_count NUMBER      := 0;
  CURSOR cr_acnum
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT(acnum) FROM tab1;
  CURSOR cr_prod(l_acnum_dum IN VARCHAR2)
  IS
    SELECT prod FROM tab1 WHERE acnum = l_acnum_dum;
BEGIN
  OPEN cr_acnum;
  FETCH cr_acnum bulk collect INTO l_acnum;
  CLOSE cr_acnum;
  FOR i IN l_acnum.first .. l_acnum.last
  LOOP
    OPEN cr_prod(l_acnum(i));
    FETCH cr_prod bulk collect INTO l_prod;
    CLOSE cr_prod;
    FOR m IN l_prod.first .. l_prod.last
    LOOP
      IF m          <> 1 THEN
        IF l_prod(m) = l_prod(m-1) THEN
          l_prod2   := l_prod(m);
        ELSE
          l_prod2 := l_prod2||'|'||l_prod(m);
        END IF;
      ELSE
        l_prod2 := l_prod(m);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    UPDATE tab2 SET prod = l_prod2 WHERE acnum = l_acnum(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This pl/sql block is taking ages to complete. Is there anyway I can achieve the same through query rather than PL/SQL or may be by efficient PL/SQL. I tried BULK COLLECT also but of no use. Data is in Oracle DB. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: it has to be in plsql or can be sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your input. I achived the same using your inputs. I used 2 step solution:

Step 1) Create a lookup table for product and account no.

```
create table lkup_tbl
as SELECT  acnum, LISTAGG(Prod, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Prod) product
FROM (select distinct acnum, Prod from  tab1) tab
GROUP BY acnum;
```

Step 2) Now update all the tables by joining this lookup table.

```
update  tab2 t1
set (t1.Prod)  = (select product from  lkup_tbl t2
where t2.acnum = t1.acnum
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will concatenate those values as long as they don't exceed a certain total length.  You may also want to do a subquery to dedupe them if there are any dupes.

Update: here is with LISTAGG

```
update table2 set Prod = (
SELECT LISTAGG(t1.Prod, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t1.Prod) "Prod"
  FROM Table1 t1
where t1.acnum = table2.acnum)
```

Comment: wm_concat is an unsupported function according to Oracle.  Maybe use listagg instead?

Comment: listagg would work--old versions don't have it though

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g so listagg is supported. Problem is how do I update data in tab2?

Comment: I would consider using the list agg to create some sort of temporary table so the calulation is outside the update.  IN SQL Server we can create a temp table and index it so that it woudl be fast when it got to the updating part. I dont; knwo enough about oracle to say if it woudl help keep the table from being blocked for less time, but typically in SQl Server anything that can reduce teh time of the actual update can help with that.